# Returning different subtypes c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, covariant-return-types

Coming from a Java background, I'm having trouble understanding the inheritance functionality of c++. I'm trying to write a class that returns different subtypes, based on some logic inside the function. Code explaines better:

Supertype.h

```
class SuperType {

public:

virtual SuperType * functionA() const = 0;
};
```

SubTypeA.h

```
class SubTypeA : public SuperType{

public:

    SuperType * functionA() const override;
};
```

SubtypeA.cpp

```
SuperType * SubTypeA::functionA() const {

    if(someassertionIsTrue()){
        return new SubTypeA();
    }else{
        return new SubTypeB();
    }
}
```

SubTypeB.h

```
class SubTypeB : public SuperType{

public:

    SuperType * functionA() const override;
};
```

SubtypeB.cpp

```
SuperType * SubTypeB::functionA() const {

    if(someassertionIsTrue()){
        return new SubTypeA();
    }else{
        return new SubTypeB();
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error the `return new SubTypeB` line saying:

`Cannot initialize return object of type 'SuperType *' with an rvalue of type 'SubTypeB *'`

So questions:

- Is this type of logic even possible in c++?
- If so, how?

Comment: Hi, can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: Do `SubTypeA` and `SubTypeB` *both* inherit from `SuperType`? Please create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes

Comment: On an unrelated note, if `functionA` do the same thing in both sub-classes, why override it in the sub-classes? Why not implement it in the base-class only?

Comment: Your code (put together in the correct order) [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/6a4onG). Are you including both the `SubTypeA.h` and `SubTypeB.h` header files in both source files? Do you have any forward-declaration of any of the classes? Do you get the same error for both `SubtypeA.cpp` and `SubtypeA.cpp` source files?

Comment: hmm, the meta code seems fine indeed. All right I'll pick it up from here then

Comment: Unrelated, but you should probably replace the raw pointer by `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to solve the compilation problem. Check if you included `SubTypeB.h` in `SubTypeA.cpp` and `SubTypeA.h` in `SubTypeB.cpp`.

You might wanna solve the underlying problem you probably have. 
You want to create an object of type `SubTypeB` in `SubTypeA` and visa-versa. So the class `SubTypeA` need `SubTypeB` to compile and `SubTypeB` needs `SubTypeA`. So you have a circular dependency which is almost always a design flaw you have to solve. Since the definitions in the headers are not dependent on the other class you can get it to compile but this might change if in the future.

How to solve this flaw depends on what you want to do and if this construct even makes sense. You could write a third class or just a function which implements the logic of `functionA` and creates one of the two `SubTypes` depending on the condition.